# Need to remove white space between words in BizTalk 2016

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2016, biztalk-mapper

I need to remove spaces between words in BizTalk 2016.

The source schema will contain a string with spaces in words, but before mapping it to the destination schema I need to remove spaces in between the words.

One example of the exact requirement is as follows:
The source string will be "Reduced LOS" and I need to remove the space in between the words and make it as "ReducedLOS".

Is there any built in functoid in BizTalk that can help me achieve this or do I have to write custom code using scripting functoid?. And if I have to write the code can anyone, please give me some examples.

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3905186/6271132

Comment: No out of the box functionality, so yes, a scripting functoid with the code mabiyan linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpy using a Scripting Functoid with the below code will do the trick if all you want is spaces removed.

```
public string RemoveSpaces(string stringWithSpaces)
{
    return stringWithSpaces.Replace(" ","");
}
```

[image]

If you want other white space removed, see [Efficient way to remove ALL whitespace from String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219454/efficient-way-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-string)